# How do I know if magento index is actually processing or stuck

Tags: magento-1.9, indexing

I added 50,000 products using magmi and `catalog URL rewrites` and `Catalog SearchIndex` are processing for last 16 hours. Some categories show blank page even though, they have thousands of products in them.

How do I know if index is actually processing and not stuck?

Comment: Try using top and/or htop to see if there is something running and consuming resources.

Answer (score 3):

You can log into MySQL using command line client and run query to check what queries are being executed at the moment:

```
show full processlist;
```

If you see `insert` or `delete` queries accessing index tables, run status query a couple of times and check if "Time" column changes. If its value is being changed and query is still there, it may mean that your indexing is not hang and is still running.

Answer (score 1):

You can check index status using following shell command.

```
php indexer.php --status
```